# Evaluating the limit for a multivariable function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^2y^m}{x^4 +  y^{2m}},& (x,y) \ne 0\\
 (0,0),& (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}
$$

Now I need to find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ for $m=-1$.

Now, for $m = -1$ the given function transforms to :

$$f = \dfrac{x^2y}{x^4y^2 + 1}.$$ As $(x,y) \to (0,0)$$ I need to find the limit:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2y}{x^4y^2 + 1} $$

Now , $$\left| \dfrac{x^2y}{x^4y^2 + 1}\right| \le  \left|x^2y\right|$$

Now as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ the limit on right hand side goes to $0$.

Hence the answer must be $0$.

Is my solution and answer correct ?

Thank you.

Comment: I improved some of the formatting in your post, please check to make sure that I did not alter its mathematical meaning.

Comment: @Math1000: Thanks,for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2y}{x^4y^2 + 1}=0$$

You really did not need to go as far as comparison because  the numerator of the function goes to zero while the denominator goes to $1$

Thus the fraction approaches zero.